# How to give a border to an anchor tag's background image?

Tags: html, css

How can I give and adjust the border just around the background image of a anchor tag ?
Now I have a border of my anchor tags as the width and height are predefined. Can I give border around the background images of these anchor tags namely "Next" and "Prev" ??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>jQuery UI Dialog: Hide the Close Button/Title Bar</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

    .mySlider
    {
       //
    }

    .shadow_div
    {
      //
    }

    .mySlider img
    {
        width:800px;
        height:480px;
        display:none;

    }

    .Parent_Slider > a
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:bold;
        width:32px;
        height:32px;
        position:absolute;
        top:45%;
        text-indent:-9999px;
    }

    .Next_Class
    {
        right:282px;
        background-image:url(Images/rightarrow.jpg);
        border:1px solid white;
    }

    .Prev_Class
    {
        left:282px;
        background-image:url(Images/leftarrow.jpg);
    }

    ul.Round_Buttons
    {
        position:relative;
        left:35%;
        top:5px;
        text-decoration:none;
        list-style-type:none;
        text-indent:-9999px
    }

   ul.Round_Buttons li
   {
       float:left;
       background-color:white;
       margin:1px 5px;
       padding:0px 7px;
       border-radius:50%;
       border-width:1px;
       border:1px solid #3610a5;
       cursor:pointer;
       box-shadow:1px -1px 3px 1px #3610a5;
       transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
       -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;

   }

    ul.Round_Buttons li:hover
    {
        transform:rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    }


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      //


    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Parent_Slider">
    <div id="my_image_slider" class="mySlider">
        <img id="1" src="Images/bmw.jpg" alt="" title="Audi India"/>
        <img id="2" src="Images/audi.jpg" alt="" title="BMW India" />
        <img id="3" src="Images/aston-martin.jpg" alt="" title="Aston-Martin APAC" />
        <img id="4" src="Images/bugatti.jpg" alt="" title="Buggatti APAC" />
        <img id="5" src="Images/koenigsegg.jpg" alt="" title="Koenigsegg APAC" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="Next_Class">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="Prev_Class">Prev</a>
</div>
    <div class="shadow_div" >
        <ul class="Round_Buttons">
            <li id="1st_Round"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="2nd_Round"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="3rd_Round"><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li id="4th_Round"><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li id="5th_Round"><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't use CSS to do this; as the background-image can't be targeted . You'd have to add the border in your image-editing program, unless the `<a>` element uses *only* a background-image, without text-content, and/or is predictably sized. But with the information you've shared we can't say, and guessing does nobody any favours.

Comment: Please provide some further details. Example code would be necessary, and you could also create a jsFiddle to help people answering.

Comment: it depends on the case, if you know the exact position and size of the background image, we should have some solution.

Comment: Hm, sorry, I meant **relevant** example code, not your whole code dump.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a border to a background image with css, but there are probably some alternatives. Without more details it's hard to say the best route but assuming you know the dimensions of the image, you could just set the border of the `<a>` tag and make its width/height match the image:

```
a {
   background:url(http://www.vision-call.co.uk/images/stories/events/sample.jpg);
   border:3px solid red;
   display:block;          
   height:315px; /*height of image*/
   width:420px; /*width of image*/
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UJ82/)

**Update** Based on your updated question with the code, I made another fiddle:

[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkMg8/1/)

Same idea. Note that the `<a>`'s dimensions match that of the image, and the border is applied to the `<a>`, giving the impression that the background image has the border. Obviously, the images I'm using are just samples and don't look great, but this technique should work for you.